# :nth-child(even) doesn't behave as expected

Tags: html, css

I am making a custom table and I need every odd list row to be colored but for some reason   `.table:nth-child(even){ background-color: #ff9900 !important; }` is not working, sometimes even coloring the whole parent element instead of children. I have tried switching from chosing even to odd and vice versa but it still got me nowhere and I can't figure out why even though the .table is actually parent of multiple children.

```css
.table {
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    border-spacing: 0 50px;


}

  .table:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #ff9900 !important;
}


.thead {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
}

.tr {
   height: 60px;
   display: flex;

    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0 2rem;

}


.th {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-spacing: 0;
    text-align: start;
    flex: 1;
}

.td {
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: start;
    flex: 1;
  color:red;

}
```

```html
<div class="table" >
        <div class="thead" >
            <div class="th" >ID zahteva</div>
            <div class="th" > Ime i prezime </div>
            <div class="th" >Datum od</div>
            <div class="th" >Datum do</div>
            <div class="th" >Lokacija</div>
            <div class="th" >Cena</div>
            <div class="th" >Telefon</div>
            <div class="th" >Email</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td" >ID zahteva</div>
            <div class="td" > Ime i prezime </div>
            <div class="td" >Datum od</div>
            <div class="td" >Datum do</div>
            <div class="td" >Lokacija</div>
            <div class="td" >Cena</div>
            <div class="td" >Telefon</div>
            <div class="td" >Email</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td" >ID zahteva</div>
            <div class="td" > Ime i prezime </div>
            <div class="td" >Datum od</div>
            <div class="td" >Datum do</div>
            <div class="td" >Lokacija</div>
            <div class="td" >Cena</div>
            <div class="td" >Telefon</div>
            <div class="td" >Email</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td" >ID zahteva</div>
            <div class="td" > Ime i prezime </div>
            <div class="td" >Datum od</div>
            <div class="td" >Datum do</div>
            <div class="td" >Lokacija</div>
            <div class="td" >Cena</div>
            <div class="td" >Telefon</div>
            <div class="td" >Email</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why are you using classed `div`s instead of using the actual `table`, `th`, `tr`, and `td` tags?

Comment: @Austin - That's ridiculous. Tables shouldn't be used for general layout, but for tabular data, not only are they fine, that's what the bloody `table`s are _for_.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I actually tried to implement this with ordinary table elements but because of specificity of what I am building, combined with my not so good css skills, I decided to move to div approach and we don't need SEO on this anyways but I am still curios why the nth:child is not working, regardless of that type of content I want to make

Comment: Where is your <tbody>? Used with divs with "display: table-row-group;". A table has a thead and a tbody. Inside the thead should be th's, and inside the tbody should be tr's. Inside of tr there should be td's.

Comment: `.table:nth-child(even)` is not what you need. You actually want `.table :nth-child(even)`. Note the space!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using div elements for creating custom tables, there is a small change need in your HTML and CSS like you need to wrap tr elements in one main wrapper so CSS can detect even and odd. I have added colors for showing the UI but you can change accordingly. Please check below updated code :-

```css
.table {
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    border-spacing: 0 50px;


}

  .table .tbody .tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #ff9900 !important;
}


  .table .tbody .tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #55e3d6 !important;
}

.thead {
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
}

.tr {
   height: 60px;
   display: flex;

    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0 2rem;

}


.th {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-spacing: 0;
    text-align: start;
    flex: 1;
}

.td {
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: start;
    flex: 1;
  color:red;

}
```

```html
<div class="table">
        <div class="thead" >
            <div class="th" >ID zahteva</div>
            <div class="th" > Ime i prezime </div>
            <div class="th" >Datum od</div>
            <div class="th" >Datum do</div>
            <div class="th" >Lokacija</div>
            <div class="th" >Cena</div>
            <div class="th" >Telefon</div>
            <div class="th" >Email</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tbody">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td" >ID zahteva</div>
            <div class="td" > Ime i prezime </div>
            <div class="td" >Datum od</div>
            <div class="td" >Datum do</div>
            <div class="td" >Lokacija</div>
            <div class="td" >Cena</div>
            <div class="td" >Telefon</div>
            <div class="td" >Email</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td" >ID zahteva</div>
            <div class="td" > Ime i prezime </div>
            <div class="td" >Datum od</div>
            <div class="td" >Datum do</div>
            <div class="td" >Lokacija</div>
            <div class="td" >Cena</div>
            <div class="td" >Telefon</div>
            <div class="td" >Email</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td" >ID zahteva</div>
            <div class="td" > Ime i prezime </div>
            <div class="td" >Datum od</div>
            <div class="td" >Datum do</div>
            <div class="td" >Lokacija</div>
            <div class="td" >Cena</div>
            <div class="td" >Telefon</div>
            <div class="td" >Email</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td" >ID zahteva</div>
            <div class="td" > Ime i prezime </div>
            <div class="td" >Datum od</div>
            <div class="td" >Datum do</div>
            <div class="td" >Lokacija</div>
            <div class="td" >Cena</div>
            <div class="td" >Telefon</div>
            <div class="td" >Email</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Let me know if it works for you or not.